# A huge discrepancy between the number of unique visitors reported in Google Analytics and those tracked by the Custom unique visitor count

Tags: codeigniter, analytics, counter, visitor-pattern

I implemented a custom unique visitor counter to my website developed in Codeigniter. The visitor counter is based on cookies as follows

**On Page Load**

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$check_visitor = $this->input->cookie(urldecode($pageTitle  + $slug), FALSE);
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
if ($check_visitor == false) {
$cookie = array(
    "name"   => urldecode($pageTitle  + $slug),
    "value"  => "$ip",
    "expire" =>  time() + 1800,
    "secure" => false
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
// then increase count by one in the table
$this->news->update_counter(urldecode($slug));
}
```

My cookie expiration time is 30 mins.
When I compare my custom counts with Google analytics counts there is a large difference.

I also added a list of crawlers and bots to filter the counts but didn't work.

Can someone help me out to address this problem?

Comment: why don't you using google api to capture the unique visitors ? any specific reason ? 
you can get this count directly after hitting google api
please review the reference : 
[link](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2011/02/mastering-unique-visitors-in-api.html)

Comment: Thanks Hash but I require to develop my site Google Analytics independed. Means my visitor counter should also work correctly even in that situation when I don't use Google analytics.